# Display List as a table on Hover?

Tags: html, angular

I have the following situation for a project i am working on:
[image]

Currently, when I hover over "Idle HF" (From Image), I get a list displayed with comma separated values. I need this to be in a table, each value in one row and I need to achieve this through Angular JS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Based on request:

```
  <p-column field="tdst" header="TDST" [style]="{'text-align': 'left'}">
    <ng-template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
      <span title = {{row.tdlist}}>{{row.tdst}}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
```

In the code,
tdlist is the python list I am fetching to display on hover.
tdst is the column value on which hover property is to be implemented

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ui.bootstrap` [**tooltips**](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tooltip). They can pull the template, populate it with your array, and display it on hover/click/function call. Here is a small demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <span uib-tooltip-template="'template.html'" tooltip-placement="bottom-right" tooltip-trigger="'mouseenter'">Idle HF (in a table)</span>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Values</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in array">
        <td>{{ x }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </script>

</div>
```

Your template can be a separate file, which you can decorate however you want to fit the data.

Comment: Appreciate the help. But I am using Angular for table instead of the HTML tags i.e; <p-datatable>, <p-column>,...

I am not sure if the script tag works for these

And yes, I do have a separate file for template